# How to combine versions from indirect dependent projects into a single project

Tags: java, maven, version

I've got three maven projects like (all independent)

- P1
- P2
- P3

P1 and P3 are standalone products and P2 is a plugin in P1 which uses the endpoints from P3 to display data in P1/P2.
Now my problem is, that each project got it's own version, for example P1 = 1.0.0, P2 = 2.0.0 and P3 = 3.0.0 and I don't know how to achieve a "combined versioning". How to release a new version of P2 which has indirect dependencies to P1 and P3 and directly know, which version of P2 should I use to fit P1 and P3. I thought of something like P2 = combined version of P1 and P3 = 1.0.0.3.0.0

Sorry, I don't know how to describe the question clearly.

Answer (score 0):

Put all three projects into one multi-module project.

Then you can build them together and they have the same version all the time.

It is much easier if you know that version `3.0.0` of P2 is always in combination with version `3.0.0` of P1 and P3.